# "in the most unexpected way" vs "in the most unexpected of ways"

Tags: sentence, phrase-usage

For instance, which one I should use in the following sentence?

> It wasn't until eight years later that I got to hear about the Johnsons again, though [...].

Are they the same? If not, how to they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at   NGram, **unexpected way/ways** appears to be the most used  between the two.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most%20unexpected%20ways,most%20unexpected%20of%20ways,%20most%20unexpected%20way&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,most%20unexpected%20ways;,c0;.t1;,most%20unexpected%20of%20ways;,c0;.t1;,most%20unexpected%20way;,c0)

The meaning is the the same, probably **of** is a short for **of all**